# Mythic GM fate system and Pathfinder character skills

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, mythic-rpg

I am having trouble understanding how you combine these. Specifically, the perception and knowledge skills seem like they would have quite a bit of weight on the questions asked. The other skills seem like they would influence the outcome of the answers as well. Could someone help me understand how these two systems would function together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by recommending strongly that when using Mythic you use the game system of your choice to handle things it's good at - and Mythic for narrative or story element things.

As an example, a situation arises where the Drwavern Cleric PC heads to a bar to dig out some information on a group of thugs that have terrorized the area.

- [Is this a Rough Place?] is answered by Mythic as Pathfinder hasn't really got rules support for this question. Given known facts (ie thugs hang out there, we might choose 'likely')
- [Are the thugs present?] is also answered by Mythic. We know the thugs are sometimes here, and the interest of the story indicates they should be, so lets try 'Very likely'.
- [Does the Dwarf spot them] - Answered by Pathfinder. There are rules in there for making Perception tests
- [Who goes first in the brawl that ensues?] - Answered by Pathfinder. Initiative rules are game stuff, not narrative stuff

In the version of Mythic GM system I have, questions are rated in terms of 'very unlikely' through 'almost certain' in terms of the probability of that outcome - I forget the terms exactly used but I'm reasonably sure there is guidance in terms of what probabilities these might represent. In order to mesh with another system (sure as Pathfinder or a D20 game) you would need to convert the likelihood of success on a given roll to a percentage in order to map it to the Mythic probabilities, ***if you decide to handle the roll in Mythic instead of your game system***.

So, in a D20 type system you might look at the situation where your character, a Dwarvern Cleric, is attempting to stare down unruly ruffians in a bar, and think that his Intimidate of +3 against a target of 12 looks like it fits the 'likely' category of success, and so engage with the Mythic systems using that category.

***In short, the answer I'm suggesting is that you consider for situations that are covered by game system rules handling those with the game system. If that isn't what you want to do, then an approach is to arrive at a percentage chance for your chosen situation, which in game terms will likely be effected by the characters skills and traits - but also by the current narrative and your own predilections for story structure and flow***.

Again, for example, should our brave Cleric above decide to track the ruffians to their hovel, you might decide that's 'very unlikely' - he has average perception at best, it's dark and he no specific talents in tracking enemies. For a ranger in the same circumstance you might decide the likelihood is 'very likely' as he has an ability called 'tracking', great perception, a pet hound that can track, an Amulet of Finding Ne'er-do-wells +3, a Fate Aspect of 'No one has a nose like mine', or whatever else your system of choice cares about.

With Mythic being largely system agnostic, unfortunately, it can require some creative interpretations to get it working with your system of choice and is often more of an art than a science. In general the system works well when 'narrative' or story structure questions are handled by Myhtic and the game system handles the things it normally does - like combat, movement and so forth. If you compare this to playing with a GM, then cases where there are printed rules for things (Perception, Will Saves, Combat, spellcasting) I would recommend using them, for other things (Is it light in this room, is it foggy this evening, can I find a blacksmith in this village, does the Orc want to gamble instead of fight) you use Mythic.